# What version of an EAR is installed on Websphere?

Tags: jakarta-ee, deployment, websphere, version, ear

How can I determine which version of an EAR was installed on Websphere 8.0.0.4?

In other words, how can I be sure that the latest version of my EAR is still deployed and/or is currently started in a scenario where I did not do the deployment myself?

Comment: I don't understand the question. How would the server know better than you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your EAR uses metadata for modules (e.g. by using Maven EAR plugin with option addDefaultImplementation entries that adds Implementation-Version into Manifest file), then you can see EAR version in Admin console (Applications->Application Types->WebSphere enterprise applications->select EAR->Application binaries->Application build level).
Another option is if deployer entered this information while deploying EAR.
Third option is if EAR contains version in file name (if built with Maven).